# How can I keep Task Manager from killing my program?

Tags: windows, delphi, process, message, taskmanager

Is there any way to protect my Delphi application from being killed by the Windows task manager (or others like Process Explorer)?

I think Windows messages can do that (by doing a hook and intercepting the TerminateProcess message).

I want an example of this protection. The Kaspersky Anti-Virus suites are like this; we can't end their process in Task Manager.

Comment: What legitimate reason do you have for doing this?

Comment: I suggest an alternative: Have a status flag that shows proper shutdown, and if you are started without that shutdown flag being set, make a log of it (or bigger). And then have a service which monitors your process and ensures it is running. If the user kills it, just start it up again. This is what we do with a "must be running" process which the user may mess with.

Comment: I have a suggestion: please don't do this.

Comment: What if a guy wants to write a virus, and comes on StackOverflow trying to get help to make it extra nasty. Do we help him out or not?

Comment: @Warren P, I'm not writing a virus, i'm writing a Server/Client application, and i don't want my Client App killer by someone without the Server(Administrator) Agree. Because this client app send some useful data to the server.

Comment: Then this isn't a technological problem, it's a social/education issue.  The solution is to make sure the users know that this is a legitimate process that they shouldn't be killing.  Adding in virus-like behavior will only make savvy users more suspicious.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler  : I totally agree, but anything works normally in our today's world. So I'll not keep a vulnerability form my program as the end user says it's a bug, or do not buy the soft.
But, like you said, it will make some users suspicious, but i prefer to have a minimum users suspicious and not a max users trying to kill the soft to get special "things" (like they think).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AV Programs like Kaspersky probably use a driver and use hook to prevent termination.
In your situation I would advise to set an ACL on the process, this prevents termination with Task Manager or cmdline tools (if the user does not have the Debug privilege). Of course the user can always use a tool like Process Explorer, take ownership of the process, set new ACL and Terminate.

If the user is not an administrator it would suffice to run the process in a different user context (eg launch it from a service).

Setting a process ACL is very easy with the [Jedi Windows Security Library](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/security-library/) as this [sample](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/11/08/restrict-access-to-process) shows.

Comment: oaky Remko,
This library is satisfying me, which is shown in the example could respond to my needs, because i just want something "un"-killable by newbies (uses & taskmanager !!)

Comment: @JoshEinstein Now ***that's*** civilized. +1 for the comment *and* your answer.

Answer (score 14):

As Kornel says, there are OS-level protection of processes isolated by users. But generally speaking, there's no way to stop your process from being terminated by a user with permission to do so. And a user has permission to terminate processes running as that user.

Even if you wanted to run it as SYSTEM, you couldn't use this process to interact with the logged on user. You'd need to run it as a service and it would have no GUI. You could try other approaches such as getting a DLL loaded into a process like Explorer.exe that users won't terminate because they don't want to, but that's just abusive.

It would be a very bad situation for end users if developers could just write applications that could not be terminated. If this is an internal application you might check Server Fault to see if there's some way of achieving it with Group Policy.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very bad idea.  If your program is running on someone else's computer, it's on their property, not yours, and needs to behave itself as a guest in their home.  That means you don't act as if you own the place, and you certainly don't tell the computer's owner what he can't do with his own property, such as kill a task he doesn't want running.  If you do that, then your program is no better than malware, and is likely to be treated like malware.

Comment: -1: the computer can be not their property. e.g. help desks where managers have to supervise operators, especially when they have access to sensitive data. OS is not about ethiсs, it's about programming questions

Comment: @Andy: In such a situation, there are appropriate policy-editing tools available for management to handle those situations.  And if you think that ethics can be separated from programming somehow, please don't ever touch a compiler again.  I don't want to run the risk that something you wrote ends up on my machine.

Comment: why not to describe this in detail? OP already gave his word that it's not about malware (in comments)

Comment: @Andy: Perhaps, but that doesn't stop someone else who *is* trying to write malware from finding this page.

Comment: I think knowledge should be public, you think different. It's why I would recommend to discuss such things somewhere else to avoid flaming on SO. If you think that OP doesn't deserve that very dangerous info he asks about - don't give it to him. I hope others think different

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're asking a wrong question.

You trying to solve "**what if connection will be terminated in the middle of chat with server**" problem in the wrong way. The answer is **not** to "*deny process termination*", but to "*foresee connection problems and write error-fallback code*"!

Why? Cause, obviosly, connection termination can be due to network problems (you can't deny your users to unplug machine from network) and not termination of the client!

[Why can't you trap TerminateProcess?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373)

And if you're worried about application crashed - just use [Application Restart & Recovery API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/recovery/application-recovery-and-restart-portal).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way: you could just start **2 processes** and let them "look" on each other.
If one of them was closed, let the other proceess restart it.  It will prevent newbies (as you said) from killing that process.

Sorry, but I think that your "Server/Client application" has **trojan/backdoor** abilities. "**Client app send some useful data**" , "**unkillable process**" (in your comments) seem tooooo suspicous for me.

Answer (score -1):

Create an NT-service project, service processes can't be killed with Process Manager, but are controlled by the internal service manager.