# how to disable to endprocess for my service using task manager

Tags: visual-c++

i have written my own windows service which should not kill by "endprocess" using task manager, if any one tries to do , it should alert like "Critical Process"

Comment: possible duplicate How can I keep Task Manager from killing my program? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983564/how-can-i-keep-task-manager-from-killing-my-program