# Hide a Windows Application Process from TaskManager

Tags: c#, winforms, taskmanager

I'm creating an Application which requires a Password to Exit.

so I disabled the close button and removed from TaskBar.

I'm also able to remove from TaskManager Applications Tab. But when I search in TaskManagers Processes tab, It is visible in it and the I'm able to end the process thus end the application from there. So I need to hide the Process even from there.

Can you help me in Doing this??

Comment: And what do you do when the user pulls the plug out of the wall?

Comment: I need to ask the user to enter a password. If it matches the criteria, then exit.

Comment: Voting to close: while there could be legitimate resaons to implement such behavior (feel free to tell your compelling story if you have one), but at this point there is no good reason to help with implemnting feature primarily sed by malware. At the very least such program's behavior feels aginst reasonable guidelines for securing applications and creating usable UI.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not doing this Illegally. A client asked me to make it so. Since there will be several people using his PC which and they should not be able to end the process.without authorization. so I have to achieve this. Still you think this is illegitimate ??

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov
I used an application on machines where users have to log in and have limited time to use. After that computer was automaticly locked. This is a legitimate reason to prevent process from killing. Not everybody owning a knife is a murderer

Comment: @Sarrus, but there is absolutely no need for such interesting behavior in your scenario - as long as you don't give admin privelegies to users it's most likley enough to use standard security restrictions... but if you have full admin rights - no restrinctions exist anyway :)

Comment: Not wanting to help is not a reason to vote to close.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe you know how to make a logon time limit for users on windows 98/2000/XP using standard security restrictions, because I don't :P

Comment: @Sarrus, I probably was not clear - this question is not how to prevent process from beeing killed (default behavior if it is running under different user and current user is not admin on NT-based systems), but to *hide* process from task manger and likley when current user is box admin. Agree if you need to support Win95/98 you have much harder time to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this topic:
[How can I keep Task Manager from killing my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983564/how-can-i-keep-task-manager-from-killing-my-program)
someone asked for same thing.

The best answer:

> AV Programs like Kaspersky probably use a driver and use hook to
>   prevent termination. In your situation I would advise to set an ACL on
>   the process, this prevents termination with Task Manager or cmdline
>   tools (if the user does not have the Debug privilege). Of course the
>   user can always use a tool like Process Explorer, take ownership of
>   the process, set new ACL and Terminate.
>
> If the user is not an administrator it would suffice to run the
>   process in a different user context (eg launch it from a service).

Here some information on msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This might help me. but When the system shutdown is clicked, will this prevent from shutdown and ask for password?? I do not want to ask for password. the system should shutdown normally.